# Strange issue with dired-subtree

Tags: init-file, buffers, dired, package, use-package

This is my simple config:

```
(use-package dired-subtree
        :ensure t
        :bind (:map dired-mode-map
                    ("<tab>" . dired-subtree-toggle)))
```

The first time the package is loaded (assuming all in `.emacs.d/elpa` are removed, then it works fine (though there are a huge amounts of pop-up warnings from native compilation). The subsequent times, when I attempt to `<tab>` (I've tried other key bindings too) it is always the same issue in the mini-buffer:

```
Buffer is read-only: #<buffer -directory name->
```

If I run `M-x <ret> dired-subtree-toggle <ret>`, then it works, and subsequent `<tab>`s work.